# How do I set env variables for Docker on Windows desktop?

Tags: windows-11, environment-variables, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to set up Sabnzbd and this is what I'm attempting to set:

[image]

I am getting this message:

```
s6-linux-init: warning: unable to dump kernel environment to /run/s6/container_environment: Is a directory
s6-rc: info: service s6rc-oneshot-runner: starting
s6-rc: info: service s6rc-oneshot-runner successfully started
s6-rc: info: service fix-attrs: starting
s6-rc: info: service init-migrations: starting
s6-rc: info: service init-envfile: starting
s6-envdir: fatal: unable to envdir /run/s6/container_environment: No such file or directory
s6-rc: warning: unable to start service init-envfile: command exited 111
s6-envdir: fatal: unable to envdir /run/s6/container_environment: No such file or directory
s6-rc: warning: unable to start service init-migrations: command exited 111
s6-rc: info: service fix-attrs successfully started
s6-rc: info: service legacy-cont-init: starting
s6-rc: info: service legacy-cont-init successfully started
```

I know it's not using my config setting since it starting with a fresh install.

I did a search for sabnzbd.ini on my system and I didn't find anything.

Am I setting this wrong? How do I get this to work on Windows? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In Windows, When I run the script, I usually add the needed ENV variable like this: `my command ENV_VAR=VALUE. ` Try this if you are executing some script on your desktop.

Comment: Apart from this, you can also type the Windows button and start searching "Edit The System Environment variables." there, you can add User or System ENV Vars. Sometimes you have to restart for it to take effect.

Comment: @SarthakDwivedi I don't have access to run it from the command line. Any ideas about the web gui?